# IE Debug Toolbar missing feature

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging

can I in IE Debug Toolbar view resource loading like in FireBug for FF on "Net Tab"

I want to see which files loaded, js, images and so on

can I see Ajax request for example?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

On IE, you would use Fiddler for that.

Comment: thanks, I try. my IE8 do not load some js files, I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

IE9 Developer tools support this.  You could [install the beta](http://www.beautyoftheweb.com/) and try that.

Or use [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: I can't use IE9 beta cause my issue appears only in ie6-7-8

Comment: Did you try IE9 beta in one of its compatibility modes?

Comment: No, I just delete ie9 cause I need IE8